# How can I store the response from a third party API as instance in a Django model

Tags: python, django, djoser

Edit: I have edited my question to include my code:

I am building a web API in DRF. And there's this third party API whose response returns fields like `ip_address`, `latitude`, `longitude`, etc. I have a user model (which is basically inherited from an `AbstractBaseUser`) that contains fields like `email`, `username`, `first_name` and `last_name`.  Creating an instance of this user model works.

But what I want to do is save response from this third party API as an instance of a model called Artist that has a OneToOneField with the user model whenever an instance of this user model is saved. How can I do this?

Note: I am letting Djoser, a third-party library for handling authentication, take care of the authentication endpoints on my user model. So no views involved in this project so far yet it works.

Here's my code so far:

```
import uuid
import requests

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomUserManager



class UserGeoData(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(default="0.0.0.0")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    region_iso_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    pkid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Username"), max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("First Name"), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Last Name"), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_("Email Address"), unique=True)
    usergeo = models.OneToOneField(UserGeoData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "first_name", "last_name"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Users")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = "https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=d77f75a5593e4073a6eb1bef9c35e929"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        obj, created = UserGeoData.objects.get_or_create(
            ip_address=data["ip_address"],
            defaults={
                "city": data["city"],
                "region_iso_code": data["region_iso_code"],
                "country_code": data["country_code"],
                "longitude": data["longitude"],
                "latitude": data["latitude"],
            },
        )
        self.ship = obj
        return super().save()

# class Holiday(models.Model):
#     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#     holiday_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
#     holiday_type = models.CharField(max_length=120)
#     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
# class Security(models.Model):
#     usergeodata = models.OneToOneField(UserGeoData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#     is_vpn = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here's my User manager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def email_validator(self, email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            raise ValueError(_("You must provide a valid email address"))

    def create_user(
        self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields
    ):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_("Users must submit a username"))

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError(_("Users must submit a first name"))

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError(_("Users must submit a last name"))

        if email:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            self.email_validator(email)
        else:
            raise ValueError(_("Base User Account: An email address is required"))

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=email,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(
        self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields
    ):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superusers must have is_staff=True"))

        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superusers must have is_superuser=True"))

        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_("Superusers must have a password"))

        if email:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            self.email_validator(email)
        else:
            raise ValueError(_("Admin Account: An email address is required"))

        user = self.create_user(
            username, first_name, last_name, email, password, **extra_fields
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: If you are aware of the fields returned by the third party API upfront, you can create the Artist model with the fields defined on it. And have a OneToOneField mapped to User model.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield

In case, the fields returned in the response are dynamic, you can have a JSONField(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) on the Artist model.

Comment: Which database do you use? If you work on postgresql, then you can JSONField.

Comment: Yes, I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: And where do I use the JSONField please? In place of OneToOneField ?

Comment: And I thought I would have to use signals or something?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, by overriding your custom user `save` method. Here is a simple example using [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/) that assigns a `Ship` for an user:

models.py

```py
import requests as req


class Ship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hyperdrive_rating = models.FloatField()
    starship_class = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class User(AbstractUser):
    # supposedly you want to maintain the ship in this case.
    # but may want to get rid of your actual values with models.CASCADE
    ship = models.OneToOneField(Ship, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = req.get("https://swapi.dev/api/starships/10")
        data = res.json()
        obj, created = Ship.objects.get_or_create(
            name=data["name"],
            defaults={
                "model": data["model"],
                "manufacturer": data["manufacturer"],
                "hyperdrive_rating": data["hyperdrive_rating"],
                "starship_class": data["starship_class"],
            },
        )
        self.ship = obj
        return super().save()
```

Used `AbstractUser` for the sake of simplicity.

P.S. you want python [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Comment: I use AbstractBaseUser. Is this not enough? Can I also override the save method if I use AbstractBaseUser?

Comment: And would there be need to use signals?

Comment: Yes, the `save` method is inherited by `AbstractBaseUser` from the basic `Model` class, so it also works when you call `super().save()`!

Comment: Okay good. Thank you very much. And doing this would ensure that once a user is created, the artist model is automatically filled with json data from the third party api even without the use of signals? Because like I said, the user was created successfully till I used a signal to trigger the artist model to also get created once the user is created. And then I was told "unable to create account".

Comment: No need to use signals in this case. And, since you are using `AbstractBaseUser` you must have written your own [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) which should call `.save()` both on `create_user` and `create_superuser`. As you can see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/) signals are you used when you want to trigger more than one event for a single action.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have a similar case. But in this case no third party API is involved. I get the same "Unable to create account " on postman.

Comment: I am still getting the error "Unable to create account"

Comment: I have edited my post to include the full code.

Comment: Still missing your manager so I can reproduce it. But make sure your payload contains `"user", "username", "first_name" and "last_name"` key-pairs. And, change `self.ship = obj` to `self.usergeo = obj` under the save method. Please, also note that you have a `one-to-one` relation, so you can't have the same object related to two different users.

Comment: Okay. Let me edit the main post to include my User manager. And I will take your suggestions right away.

Comment: And please, kindly upvote my question. I have been banned from posting further questions. Thanks .

Comment: With the changes that a mentioned it works smoothly. I would have upvoted your question if it was correctly structured from the beginning, make sure you always read the rules.